# Adding alt text and aria label to fav icon

Tags: html, accessibility, favicon, wcag2.0

How can we add alt text and aria label to a fav icon?

Tried the following but has no effect.

I am questioning whether a fav icon even needs these details but see no references in W3 to confirm whether it is needed or not.

Pls advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page Title</title>
  <link 
    rel="icon" 
    type="image/x-icon" 
    href="https://www.company.com/favicon.ico" 

    <!-- This doesn't do anything. And do I even need this -->
    alt="some sample" 
    aria-label="I AM ARIA LABEL"
  >
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading 12</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph. 1</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The favicon is 1.) not an `img` tag and 2.) does not appear in the `body` of the HTML code, so you don't need an `alt` attribute or aria label attribute for it since it won't be read by screenreaders.

Comment: Makes sense. But is there any official guidance on this confirming this information. I can't find any references to this.

Comment: Well, if you search the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines at https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#non-text-content you won't find the term "favicon" at all. You can find "icon", but everything in there relates to **content** or some necessary explanation of functionality, and a favicon definitely isn't content, but at most "decoration" (searching the WCAG for "icon" will only bring results that don't relate to favicon). It would have to contain some *information* to be considered content, but favicons are really too small for that (or won't even be displayed in some cases), so just forget about it

Answer (score 0):

Technically, since the `<link>` element referencing the favicon is in `<head>`, it isn't rendered in the page, and hence, can't have any alternative text or label.

In fact, the favicon is a pure decorative icon to help you quickly identify your website without the need for the user to read the URL or domain name.
As such, it  doesn't bring any useful information to blind and partially sighted users who can't distinguish enough detail allowing this quick visual recognition.

Note that, for the reasons just explained, if an alt text had been required, it should have been empty.

Answer (score -3):

`alt` or `aria-label` are not required or needed in the `<link>` tag that you have identified as a favicon to your page . as an addition to `alt`:

- the `alt` attribute only works if a specific image in the website could not be displayed.